# How to make new column in Orange Python Script

Tags: orange

I have column  " Price " . This column is continous variable.

For some reason i want to make new column called " Price_Category ". This column is Discrete variable and the values are "cheap, moderate, expensive"

for example :

if 1.45 < price <1.99 then price_category = cheap

if 1.99 < price <2.00 then price_category = moderate

if 2.00 < price <5.00 then price_category = expensive

how to do that in Python Script widget in Orange Data Mining software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about Python Script widget, but you can use Feature Constructor widget to make a discrete variable with code such as:

```
0 if price <= 1.99 else 1 if price <= 2 else 2
```

and values:

```
cheap, moderate, expensive
```